# How to upload to S3 Bucket using TinyPng API NodeJs

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, file-upload

## What I want to achieve.

---

I want to compress my images that a user uploads to my server using **TinyPng** Api and then Upload them to my s3 Bucket.

### Code

Here is my code to upload to s3 Bucket.

```
var upload = multer({
    storage: multerS3({
      s3: s3,
      bucket: 'thecuratorsbucket',
      metadata: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, {fieldName: file.fieldname});
      },
      key: function (req, file, cb) {
        const name ="images/" + file.originalname.toLowerCase().split(' ').join('-');
                const ext = MIME_TYPE_MAP[file.mimetype];
                cb(null, name + '-' + Date.now()+ '.' + ext);
        // cb(null, Date.now().toString())
      }
    })
  })

router.post('/add-product',checkAuth,upload.array("images[]", 12), adminController.postAddProduct);
```

### TinyPng Code

```
const source = tinify.fromFile("large.jpg");
source.store({
  service: "s3",
  aws_access_key_id: "AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE",
  aws_secret_access_key: "wJalrXUtnFEMI/K7MDENG/bPxRfiCYEXAMPLEKEY",
  region: "us-west-1",
  headers: {
    Cache-Control: "public, max-age=31536000"
  },
  path: "example-bucket/my-images/optimized.jpg"
});
```

link to api reference 
https://tinypng.com/developers/reference/nodejs

### Problem

---

I do not understand how to use the tinyPng code as middelware and upload to my s3 bucket.

Comment: Hi @Mitch ! I have the exact same problem. Did you manage to find the solution?

Comment: Unfortunately not and I wish TinyPNG wrote better documentation on this,